# How to get security.context at onKernelRequest event. Symfony2

Tags: symfony, listener

I'm trying to get the user session from a listener event "onKernelRequest" but but the security.context does not yet exist and returns null everytime.

How can I create a Request Listener to be read after the security context?

Thank you.

```php
class CurrencyListener implements EventSubscriberInterface {

    private $default_currency;
    private $serviceContainer;

    public function __construct($default_currency, $serviceContainer) {
        $this->default_currency = strtoupper($default_currency);
        $this->serviceContainer = $serviceContainer;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event) {
        $request = $event->getRequest();

        var_dump($this->serviceContainer->get('security.context')->getToken());
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
        return array(
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => array(array('onKernelRequest', 15)),

        );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your "onKernelRequest" listener priority to be less than 8 (the default priority of the firewall).

Look here : https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/Resources/config/security.xml#L107

Comment: Why do not listen event like *kernel.controller* when security.context should be ready instead of relying on priority?

Comment: Furthermore you should not inject the `service_container` in your services. In your example you should rather inject the old `security.context` or the more recent `security.token_storage` instead. See for example the "Avoiding your Code Becoming Dependent on the Container" section of http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection.html.